# MVC Client side validation are not working in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, data-annotations, partial-views

I have a partial view which gets populated in modal body of my home page of MVC project. Partial view holds the login form as follows -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserEmailId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserEmailId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "example@gmail.com" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserEmailId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"> Remember login
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Login", "Home")'">
                Login
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="lead">Sign up with</p>
        <ul class="list-unstyled" style="line-height: 2">
            <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span> See all your orders</li>
            <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span> Fast re-order</li>
            <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span> Save your favorites</li>
            <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span> Fast checkout</li>
            <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span> Get a gift <small>(only new customers)</small></li>
            <li><a href="/read-more/"><u>Read more</u></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

I am using a partial classes to define my data validations for the models(so that they wont get missed if I update my db first models) -

```
public class UserMetadata
{
    [Display(Name ="Username")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage ="Please enter your email address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Required field")]
    public string UserEmailId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 8 and 15 characters", MinimumLength = 8)]
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
}
```

The validations are not working on the client side. They are not getting triggered. Am I missing some script reference?

I already have "ClientValidationEnabled" set to true in my web.config.
Please help. Thanks!

Edit - 
The following is all included in my layout -

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/2d83329334.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

Comment: Have you included Jquery jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js in your layout?and if you are using button instead of submit  input make sure you are checking $('#formId').valid() to validate these controls.

Comment: @PrashantMohite - I have added script references and changed button type to submit.But still no luck.

Comment: How you are loading `partial view` on main view? using AJAX, if so then you are parse the Validator again once dynamic html was loaded on main view.

Comment: @ramiramilu I am using this - @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_Forms.cshtml");} to load my partial view.

Comment: Can you please check what's the value of $('#formId').valid() inside developer console is it true or false?

Comment: @PrashantMohite - not sure how to check that in developer console. I am using Mozilla.

Comment: @PrashantMohite do I need to give some id to my form?

Comment: $('form').valid();  try this

Comment: @PrashantMohite do I put the $('form').valid();  in view?

Comment: Let me post you a simplest possible approach within 15 minutes .

Comment: @PrashantMohite - Ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123227/discussion-between-arpymastro-and-prashant-mohite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please check below code for reference

**1. Model**

```
     public class UserMetadata
    {
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email address")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required field")]
        public string UserEmailId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
        [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 8 and 15 characters", MinimumLength = 8)]
        public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

**2. Controller**

```
   public class UserDataController : Controller
{
    // GET: Contacts/UserData
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var userData = new UserMetadata();

        return View(userData);
    }
}
```

3. view and Javascript

   ```
    @model UserMetadata
      @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Index";
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

       <h2>Index</h2>

       @using (Html.BeginForm())
       {
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="well">
           <div class="form-horizontal">
               @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-    danger" })
               <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="col-md-12">
                       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserEmailId,   htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserEmailId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "example@gmail.com" } })
                       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserEmailId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                   </div>
               </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="col-md-12">
                       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="checkbox">
                   <label>
                       <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"> Remember login
                   </label>
               </div>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="loginUser();">
                   Login
               </button>
           </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
           }
        <script>
         function loginUser()
        {
          if($('form').valid())
        {
       //redirect to some action like         window.location=somerootPath+/login/home
   }
       else
      {
       //not valid
      }
    }
   ```
4. OutPut

[image]

Ensure the highlighted js are loaded except jquery UI.

Comment: thanks for the whole explanation. I downloaded chrome and checked the SOURCES. It does not contain the - validate.js & validate.unobtrusive.js in it. I have included the references to both in Layout. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not so far if they get loaded then I think it will work definitely

Comment: Added "text/javascript" to the references in layout and now this files are visible in SOURCES. Yay

Answer (score 1):

One way of solution is:

In the html editor add 'required' field as below

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserEmailId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "example@gmail.com",@required="required" } })
```

and no need of Html.ValidationMessageFor() for this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will give it a try.